# python requests popup generating a key

Tags: javascript, python, http, popup, python-requests

I have just started my journey with Python and am just amazed at how much one can do in less than 50 lines of code.

I got stuck, however, writing an app which is to:

1. connect with a web site
2. log in using my credentials
3. fill a form
4. choose a link from the results returned by the form
5. use the link to confirm an appointment
6. use the link to book an appointment

I went all the way through but got stuck at point 6 above. Maybe this is due to something going wrong at point 5, so please let me start with what happens in step 4 :-).

I enter **step 4** with the form site generating a list of available appointments. Those are links attached to buttons, like:

```
<a class="button strong" href="/your_account/confirm?CityId=500&amp;VisitId=42204&amp;HasReferral=False" target="popup"> click to book </a>
```

NOTE: the button opens a pop-up.
I use BeatifulSoup to pick one of the links, then I convert it to a dictionary

```
entry = {'CityId'  : '500',
         'VisitId' : '42204',
         'HasReferral' : 'False'}
```

In **step 5** I continue a session which I had created with Python's requests module and POST:

```
a = my_session.post( 'https://the_website.com/your_account/confirm', data = entry)
```

What is returned in the `a` object is the pop-up. In the the pop-up's code there is a function and a button, like the ones below:

```
accept = function () {
    if (canRedirect()) {
      var url = '/your_account/reserve?key=55924c2b-9b30-4714-ad6c-8f47c72893cd';
        $.post(url, function(html) {
          $("#dynamicReservationDivCntainer").html(html);
        });
    }
};

 <button onclick="accept()" id="okButton" class="button strong right reserveConfirmButton">Click here to hit the deal</button>
```

So here is the **step 6** and my problem. When I extract the site address and key from `a.text`, like in step 5 and POST it:

```
key_dict = {'key' : '55924c2b-9b30-4714-ad6c-8f47c72893cd'}
b = my_session.post( 'https://the_website.com/your_account/reserve', data = key_dict )
```

It turns out that `b` contains a site with something like : "Failure. The key already exists in the database. Please enter another key." and nothing gets booked.

Ah, please let me know if I missed something important in the story. I tried to extract what I believe is the crux of the matter and am afraid I may have oversimplified.

Comment: I didn't try the above steps but I think that in step 6 you forgot to post `key_dict` as data - I mean to say that key_dict by its own means nothing in the http-post request.

Comment: Checked that, but did not help :-( . The issue is somewhere around the key, I think. Whenever I send it using Python's requests, it already exists. Whenever I click through the site manually, it is always ok.

Comment: I mean, I checked `my_session.post( 'https://the_website.com/your_account/reserve', data = key_dict)` and that did not work. Not sure if you meant that.

Comment: Well then make sure that you are using the same session you used for login. If there is no problem there, then maybe the problem is related with security - so try to include in your requests a known user-agent. Also are you sure the key is the only thing you need to make a reservation.

Comment: The session is the same - I see it nicely keeps things I had sent earlier (like `__RequestVerificationToken` which I skipped in description for simplicity). I had checked the header query string using Chrome's developers tool and `key` is the only thing that needs to be passed in the url in the popup. I have just checked my `User-Agent` and set it as in my browser. The headers is now as in the comment below, but this still did not help. I am sure I am missing something obvious. Mayby it is because the button in the popup is not clickable (in GUI) unsless I check a checkbox setting canRedirect

Comment: to True? Here is the request header in the 6 step: `{'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=ggjdemkduoa0tiwngz5zhijq; LXCookieMonit=1; __RequestVerificationToken_L1BhdGllbnRQb3J0YWw1=GMi6u5WetCfbiLVbyJ2OpnefBZOSg4O75V8U9RNwMecdv3-zJtj-_GUQgBqrPvO4bVww7y9aiXA9F0JpQFOXJ7NYOw4zZIkBoHegoeGTgizFPhQjwOKo7hYOjmNKmqIVKJNpihXFaq4fvvF_AIVSAw2; GlobalLang=pl; `

Comment: `LXToken=70f60b3e-7ee7-4fe8-825c-075e81a9c643', 'Content-Length': '40', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}`